# Conversion from string "~/app.config" to type 'Integer' is not valid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, app-config

In web service Gloval.asax, i put `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(New FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Web.config")))` in `Application_Start`.
Now, I have a console application. I'm try to put          `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(New FileInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory("~/app.config")))`
and i get Conversion from string "~/app.config" to type 'Integer' is not valid. Whats causes this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn option strict on and you'll see the error at compile time.

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` is a string. When you reference something in brackets after that it's expecting a character index, which obviously "~/app.config" isn't.

Try `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "/app.config"` instead.